# ReactJS: How to set disabled option in a dynamic way for sortableJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sortablejs

I'm using the npm package `react-sortablejs`. In my component I want to set the `disabled` option dynamically. Right now my component looks like this:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { }
    }

    render() {
        const   { disabled } = this.props // <-- Boolean value as property

        return (
            <List>
                <Sortable
                    options={{
                        handle   : '.sortable-handle',
                        draggable: '.sortable-item',
                        disabled : disabled // <-- Use the bool value
                    }}
                >
                    <Items>
                </Sortable>
            </List>
        )
    }
}
```

The `disabled` value is stored in the DB. If that value changes, the sortable should be disabled/enabled. But in this way it doesn't work.

The package is based on `RubaXa/Sortable`. There I can set the disabled option like this:

```
var sortable = Sortable.create(list);

document.getElementById("switcher").onclick = function () {
    var state = sortable.option("disabled"); // get

    sortable.option("disabled", !state); // set
};
```

But how do I do that in a dynamic way in a react component?

**Update**

In the way I did it, the `disabled` option is just set initially on rendering the component. If the value changes after rendering, the option is not changed, so if the value changes from `true` to `false`, the disabled-option still keeps true.

Comment: do `console.log('disabled', disabled)` and check whether the component is getting the proper updated value or not. If that `props` value will change, React will re-render the component and the will update the ui accordingly.

Comment: Yes it does, as the value is used for other things in the same component already...

Comment: What does `disabled` return? A boolean? As per their docs (https://github.com/RubaXa/Sortable#options) the `disabled` attribute requires a `true`/`false` value.

Comment: yes it returns a boolean

Comment: i think that you have to bind the whole "option" variable.
judging from the lack of maintainer in react-sortablejs, it does not really bind to nested value yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that you have to bind the whole "option" variable.
judging from the lack of maintainer in react-sortablejs, it does not really bind to nested value yet.

try to put the options on state.

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
           option : {
                        handle   : '.sortable-handle',
                        draggable: '.sortable-item',
                        disabled : true
                    }
        }
    }
```

bind the state's option

```
 <Sortable options={this.state.option}>
                    <Items>
 </Sortable>
```

And on ComponentDidUpdate() ,do this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(prevProps.disabled !== this.props.disabled){
    this.setState({option : Object.assign({}, this.state.option, {disabled: this.props.disabled})})
 }
}
```

my guts telling me that the component does not recognized the disabled update due to nested props. the whole option must be updated, so that it recognize the change.

OR>

you can pass the options as props instead.
and do the update on parent's component, each time the disabled change.